# How to write string comparator for use in set_symmetric_difference [C++]?

Tags: c++, string, comparator, alphabetical

I'm trying to use the set_symmetric_difference (C++) function in order to find all the objects that appear in only one set, but not both.

```
set<string> set1, set2; //assume filled with strings
vector<string> output;

set_symmetric_difference(set1.begin(), set1.end(), set2.begin(), set2.end(), back_inserter(output), comparator);
```

I seem to be a little bit unsure how to write the comparator to compare the strings in alphabetical order. Here's my best guess so far:

```
bool comparator(string s1, string s2)
{  
    for(int i = 0; i < min(length1,length2); i++)
    {
        if(s1[i] < s2[i]) return true;
        else if( s1[i] == s2[i]) continue;
        else return false; 
    }
}
```

I realize the above would not work, for strings Brad and Bradley, as it would say they are equivalent.
I just want to know if this modeling of true, continue, and false, is a correct way of setting up a string comparator for alphabetical order.

I'm also concerned about comparing the ascii values because uppercase compared to a lower case could throw off "alphabetical" order, though I suppose this could easily be fixed by using to_lower() on the strings.

Answer (score 1):

Use - nothing. The default comparison uses the less-than operator that is [overloaded for `string`s](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/operator_cmp) via a lexicographical comparison.